# $u(x+\vartriangle x,y+\vartriangle y)-u(x,y) = u(x,y)_x\vartriangle x+u(x,y)_y\vartriangle y+\epsilon(\vartriangle x, \vartriangle y)$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

How to show that $u(x+\vartriangle x,y+\vartriangle y)-u(x,y) = u(x,y)_x\vartriangle x+u(x,y)_y\vartriangle y+\epsilon(\vartriangle x, \vartriangle y)$, when $u$ is of $C^1$

My attempt is $u(x+\vartriangle x,y+\vartriangle y)-u(x,y) = \int_0 ^1d\frac{u(x+\vartriangle x t, y+ \vartriangle y t)}{dt}dt= \int_0^1u_x(x+\vartriangle x t,y +\vartriangle y t)\vartriangle x+u_y(x+\vartriangle x t,y +\vartriangle y t)\vartriangle ydt$

Then How should I proceed?

I tried again using mean value theorem for integrals but sill failed, does anyone have any hint on this?

Comment: Isn't that the definition of differentiability (with the extra assumption that $\epsilon\to 0$ sufficiently fast)?

Comment: Hint: write \begin{align*}
\ u(x+\vartriangle x,y+\vartriangle y)-u(x,y)=u(x+\vartriangle x,y+\vartriangle y)\\
-u(x+\vartriangle x,y)+u(x+\vartriangle x,y)-u(x,y)\
\end{align*}

and now use MVT.

Comment: $u(x+\vartriangle x,y+\vartriangle y) - u(x,y) = u(x+\vartriangle x, y')_y\vartriangle y + u(x',y)_x \vartriangle x$ where $x'$ lies between $x$ and $x+\vartriangle x$, $y'$ lies between $y$ and $y+\vartriangle y$. I do not think this is quite what I want to show. @Chilango

Comment: @koch: now use the above in a straightforward $\epsilon-\delta$ argument. (the partials are continuous).

Comment: I do not see it still. Can you write down a full proof?@Chilango